# Ember.js ember-data render double nested hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, rest, ember.js, ember-data, has-many

I am trying to build a little app using ember data and I am trying to render all songs of an artist through its albums.

My models look like:

```
App.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  albums: DS.hasMany('album', {async:true})
});

App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('App.Artist'),
  album: DS.belongsTo('App.Album')
});

App.Album = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  cover_url: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('artist'),
  songs: DS.hasMany('song', {async:true})
});
```

And in the template I am trying to render it like:

```
<script type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='artists'>
  {{#each artist in model}} 
    {{#linkTo 'artist' artist}}{{artist.name}}({{artist.albums.length}}){{/linkTo}}
   {{/each}}
   {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars', data-template-name='albums'>
      {{#each album in albums}}
        <h3>{{album.title}}</h3>
        {{#each song in album.songs}}
          {{song.title}}
        {{/each}}
      {{/each}}
</script>
```

The album title is displayed correctly but the song titles are not shown. Ember sends a request to the server loading the songs for the albums and album.songs is `DS.ManyArray:ember461`.

The response looks like:

```
{
  songs: [
  {
   id: 8
   artist_id: 1,
   album_id: 5,
   title: "title"
  }
 ]
}
```

What could be the reason for album.songs not beeing resovled?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I specified the relationships on Song incorrectly:

```
App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('App.Artist'),
  album: DS.belongsTo('App.Album')
});
```

becomes:

```
App.Song = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('artist'),
  album: DS.belongsTo('album')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a special serializer, or an older version of Ember Data, your json is wrong.

```
{
  songs: [
  {
   id: 8
   artist_id: 1,
   album_id: 5,
   title: "title"
  }
 ]
}
```

should be

```
{
  songs: [
  {
   id: 8
   artist: 1,
   album: 5,
   title: "title"
  }
 ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to change it to your format but it does not fix the problem. 

http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_relationships  Is this documentation outdated?

Comment: Changing to your format fixed some other issues I had like album.artist.title was not working before - but it does not fix the issue with the songs.